# Question about Conic Bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\pi: X\rightarrow \mathbb{P_\mathbb{R}^1}$ be a conic bundle ($\mathbb{R}$-minimal) with 3 reducible fibres. Consider $X$ as $G$-surface where $G\subset Aut_\mathbb{R}(X)$ is a group of order $5$. Hence $G$ acts on $\mathbb{P_\mathbb{R}^1}$.

How can I see that $G$ has at least $3$ fixed points on $\mathbb{P_\mathbb{R}^1}$?

Answer (score 4):

$G$ takes a reducible fiber to a reducible fiber. Hence the corresponding three points of $P^1$ form a union of $G$-orbits. But any nontrivial $G$-orbit has length $5$, hence each of these three points is fixed.

Comment: True. And moreover, since $G$ fixes three points on $\mathbb{P}^1$, it acts trivially on it. Moreover, it preserves the two component of any reducible fibre. Seems that the situation is quite not natural at all.